How do you ride a bobsleigh?
In Trackmania 2020, there are ice blocks called bobsleighs.
Here’s an image from a game trailer:
You’re supposed to stay in between the red lines, like the green, most focused car is in the above image. They’re really hard to drive on without spinning around and/or going backwards. I’ve heard that Action Key 4 (maybe 3) is helpful, but that’s not all of it.
How do you do it correctly?

Action Keys, in Trackmania, are ways to control the amount of steering keyboard players can do. They're meant to put keyboard players on more even ground with controller players. The formula for what the steering is set to is (20 * [action key number]) / 100. For example, Action Key 4 sets steering to 80% strength.


You’re supposed to stay in between the red lines

Not exactly. this is only true at lower speeds. At higher speeds, it is more efficient to simply ride the wall of the bob, at which point the skill changes from staying in between the lines to optimizing when your car is at the top of the wall versus near the bottom, so that you avoid having to steer at all.
At lower speeds (i want to say about 300 and below, though that depends on the map), you indeed want to stay in between the red lines. Tapping is one way to achieve this on kb, or as you mention, action keys can help. Action key 3 is the preferred way of doing this, but i think it's not exactly in the right range, so you'll still have to tap-steer, just not all the time.
If you find yourself spinning out, this suggests to me that you don't really have your ice driving mechanics on lock, and I'd suggest starting there. Ice driving is really sensitive to inputs that happened a while ago, so if you panic, you can oversteer without it impacting your line until later in the turn, which makes it not as evident what input was wrong.
